# Get <canvas> features inside a rectangle after drawing it

Tags: leaflet, vector-tiles, spatial-query, vector-layer, leaflet-draw

Let's start with https://jsfiddle.net/ziyuang/dfekwzhd/

Say, now I want to allow users to specify areas by drawing rectangles. After the map having a rectangular area, I want to have the information, like properties (i.e., `properties` in line 85 of the snippet) and feature IDs, of the circles inside the area.

The drawing part seems fine, for which I may use [`L.rectangle`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#rectangle) or [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw). But I am not sure about the querying part.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate on the featureGroup and use the [LatLngBounds.contains method](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#latlngbounds-contains) to find the circles within your rectangle.

`if(yourRectangle.getBounds().contains(layer.getLatLng())) { ... }`

There are more examples in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081680/get-a-list-of-markers-layers-within-current-map-bounds-in-leaflet) post.

Answer (score 1):

I use the draw tool and turf js for the intersection. I have a point GeoJSON layer (allPoints) and let the draw tool create the polygon. my code:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    featureGroup.clearLayers(); //clears prior polygon

    layer = e.layer;
    featureGroup.addLayer(layer);
    GetSelection(featureGroup);
});

function GetSelection(layer){

    var shape2 = allPoints.toGeoJSON()
    var ptsWithin2 = turf.within(shape2, layer.toGeoJSON());

    alert('Found ' + ptsWithin2.features.length + ' features'); 
    alert("results "+JSON.stringify(ptsWithin2));
};
```